# Video Tutorials resources for IT Security

Tags: professional-education

I am looking for Video Tutorials for IT Security or related. Something like *khanacademy.org* but for IT Security.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

SANS security institute has many many videos on you tube

Answer (score 6):

there are some good security videos on http://www.securitytube.net/ ... there is also http://www.irongeek.com/

Answer (score 4):

A few I would recommend:

- http://vimeo.com/pauldotcom - Videos mainly on the use of various security tools
- http://www.youtube.com/user/strandjsgmail - Another covering mainly security tools
- http://www.youtube.com/user/sansinstitute - SANS YouTube
- http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/hackingillustrated - jliendo mentioned Irongeek in his suggestions, I would recommend it as well. His site has a lot of different videos covering a video variety of topics.

Answer (score 4):

Some of the vids from BT are decent.  Also, they have some alright courses if you want to get up to speed quickly on netsec std practices.  http://www.backtrack-linux.org/

On an unrelated side note: OP, AWESOME choice for a name.  Makes me want to change mine to anonce :)

Answer (score 3):

Securitytube was already mentioned here, but here is the version with classification: http://tools.securitytube.net/index.php?title=Open_Security_Training, also from cryptocity: http://pentest.cryptocity.net/ (just search a bit).

Answer (score 1):

This website offers some pretty good starting videos on different topics in Computer Security too:

http://security-freak.net/videos.html

Answer (score 0):

Another site with videos about security is [Open security training](http://opensecuritytraining.info/). They have very detailed videos on various topics on computer security.